# How to get value from model for Html.Label?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.label

I want to place the value of a field (property) from model into Html.Label. Something like this:

```
@Html.Label(item => item.Title)
```

I don't want a label for item.Title (like `Html.LabelFor( model => model.Title)`). But I want to put the value of `item.Title` in the label as text (string). So the result in run-time should be like this:

```
<label>Some Title</label>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.Label(Model.Title)
```

It should work

**EDITED**

or this:

```
<label>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Title)</label>
```

Comment: Wow, that was this simple :))). Thank you @melvas.

Answer (score 6):

```
<label>@Model.Title</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following seems like a more appropriate way of adding a label to a field.

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeValue, Model.SomeLabel)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this helped me and maybe it will help someone else too.

```
@Html.Label("Name of the label", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```